# Weird behavior using dom-if template in a list element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, polymer-2.0

I have a weird problem with the use of dom-if. I have a list of elements that displayed a status with different colors when something is failing and also displaying the count of children elements failing.

The change of color is working fine (`data-status$`) but the displayed of the count does not work correctly.

To hide the count I've made a function `isInFailure` that return a boolean depending of a count value, but the dom-if is only execute when I click on the `li` element, like is digest cycle is not completed yet:

```
isInFailure(entity) {
    return entity.nbFailure > 0;
}
```

My html look like this:

```
...
<li on-click="selectEntity" class="entity">
    <span class="name">{{item.name}}</span>
    <div class="status">
        <span class="label-value">Entity Status</span>
        <span class="value" data-status$="{{item.value}}">{{item.value}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alerts">
        <div class="pill">                                                
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[isInFailure(item)]]">
                 <span class="badge" data-status$="{{item.value}}">[[item.nbFailure]]</span>
            </template>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: how do you set the nbFailure property?

Comment: ```this.set(`data.${index}.nbFailure`, value);```and isInFailure return true or false according to the new value. The if is execute when I click somewhere in the component, otherwise, nothing happen.

Comment: Have you tried adding restamp=true to the dom-if template as this will remove and add the template(with all the changes) for change of if value.